# ASP.NET Self hosted Web API with IE – This page cannot be displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I am trying to invoke my service locally but IE and Edge are not able to find it.

Below is the code snippet I have and my console app is working without any error.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/";

        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start(url: baseAddress))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service Listening at " + baseAddress);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.EnableCors();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

WebController.cs

```
public class Web
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class WebController : ApiController
{
    Web[] websites = new Web[] 
    { 
        new Web { Id = 1, Name = "XYZ", Description = "XYZ"}, 
        new Web { Id = 2, Name = "ABC", Description = "ABC"}
    };

    // GET api/Web 
    public IEnumerable Get()
    {
        return websites;
    }

    // GET api/Web/5 
    public Web Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return websites[id];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Web();
        }
    }

    // POST api/values 
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post method called with value = " + value);
    }

    // PUT api/values/5 
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Put method called with value = " + value);
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5 
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Delete method called with id = " + id);
    }
}
```

I am invoking my service on IE like everyone does: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/web to GET entire Web Object.

I have installed two additional packages, OWIN and CORS.

Could someone help find a solution for this issue.

Comment: Can you edit/update your question to include whatever error message it is that IE/Edge log to the devtools console? And what does your JavaScript code that’s making the request look like?

Comment: try to use chrome/postman. I don't know about edge but I had recently similiar problem with IE because it has problems to resolve localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried and your api works correctly in Edge and Chrome. It can be that IE don't send correct Accept header which causes to either server to return wrong result or error or IE cannot interpret the response. Actually, I have check and IE offers to save json file because it cannot display it correctly.

To show it explicitly I have modified you code a bit:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string type = null)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    if (type == "json")
    {
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(websites));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }
    else if (type == "xml")
    {
        response.Content = new StringContent("<xmlTag>Value</xmlTag>");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
    }

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Try follow http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/web?type=json and http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/web?type=xml urls and check yourself.